# How to implement unified logging for a Maven/Ant/command line tool?

Tags: maven, logging, ant, slf4j, command-line-interface

I develop a code generation tool which can be

- invoked from the command line
- used via an Ant task
- used via a Maven plugin
- maybe more to come.

In order to make code generation traceable to the end-user ("what is happening now?"), I'd like to output log statements. They will be in different levels from trace to fatal errors, so generally it is just plain standard logging.

However, I'd like to output my statements using the log capabilities of the hosting build tool.

- Maven provides a logging interface to plugins.
- CLI has none.
- I haven't written an Ant task for ages but I think there's also an interface for logging.

My idea was to use something like SLF4J as a logging API in my tool and then somehow "redirect" log messages to the hosting build tool or directly to the console, but I don't know how to implement this at the moment. I also guess I am missing a few fragments here.

My question is, basically, which direction should I further investigate.

- Do I additionally need `log4j` or `logback`?
- Is `appender` the right concept I should focus on?
- Do I have to implement, create and configure appenders for each of the hosting tools?
- Should I do this in runtime or can it somehow be configured?

Comment: http://ant.apache.org/manual/listeners.html

Comment: For Maven CLI look here: http://maven.apache.org/maven-logging.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- write a simple logging interface that abstracts all the specialties of the different tools. You may be inspired by other logging frameworks (slf4j, log4j 2.0)
  e.g.:

  ```
  public interface Mylogger {
      void debug(String msg, Object... args);
      void info(String msg, Object... args);
      //...
  }
  ```
- in each Plugin/Tool do the following

  - Instanciate the tool specific logger, or use the one given to your plugin (in the case of CLI use the logger of your choice (log4j, slf4j,...)
  - create a proxy implementing your logging interface which delegates to the tool specific logger
  - inject the logger into your code generation tool

Comment: Yes, I think this is a way to go. Thank you!